# Order of runloop events with CADisplayLink and Touch events?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitouch, nsrunloop, cadisplaylink

I would like to know if the touch events are called before the displayLink in the same runloop cycle.  Does anyone know the answer to this?

Comment: The problem with your questions is, in what release? And if I saw 5.0,  is (will) it be the same in the future. If Apple has not specified this then you can make no assumptions. I used a CADisplayLink on the Mac, and I believe (but don't know for sure) that it may get scheduled even if there are other messages queued, and there could be several cycles between it running and the runLoop. What you get with a display link is somewhat orthogonal to what you get with a normal runloop.

Comment: I agree with David H. eg this link http://www.ananseproductions.com/game-loops-on-ios/ talks about no breathing room for input processing when the frame generation gets delayed